# How do I escape a foreach loop during last iteration?

Tags: c#, list

```
foreach (Item i in Items)

 {
      do something with i;
      do another thing with i (but not if last item in collection);
 }
```

Comment: Sometimes you can restate this problem to be more tractable. Here's an article I wrote about the last time someone asked me this question: http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2009/04/13/restating-the-problem.aspx

Comment: thanks for the well written article, but while im not an advanced programmer, i still want to know how to determine the last item regardless of the actual purpose at the moment. I thought the question is clearer than any of my other conflated ones.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have a [helper class for this](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/miscutil/usage/smartenumerable.html) in [MiscUtil](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/miscutil). Sample code (from the first link):

```
foreach (SmartEnumerable<string>.Entry entry in
         new SmartEnumerable<string>(list))
{
    Console.WriteLine ("{0,-7} {1} ({2}) {3}",
                       entry.IsLast  ? "Last ->" : "",
                       entry.Value,
                       entry.Index,
                       entry.IsFirst ? "<- First" : "");
}
```

This is simpler if you're using .NET 3.5 and C# 3 so you can use extension methods and implicit typing:

```
foreach (var entry in list.AsSmartEnumerable())
{
    Console.WriteLine ("{0,-7} {1} ({2}) {3}",
                       entry.IsLast  ? "Last ->" : "",
                       entry.Value,
                       entry.Index,
                       entry.IsFirst ? "<- First" : "");
}
```

The nice thing about this over using a `for` loop is that it works with `IEnumerable<T>` instead of `IList<T>` so you can use it with LINQ etc without buffering everything. (It maintains a single-entry buffer internally, mind you.)

Comment: That's nice.  Have looked at your MiscUtil library before but got a bit overwhelmed with all that was there.  I'm sure there are loads of nice things like this.  If only I had time to go and look. :)

Comment: "usually in order to output some sort of separator between items or something similar" - exactly my issue

Comment: It's a bit of a grab-bag, yes. At some point I should either separate it out or at least move it onto code.google.com. It's just a case of finding the time... On the plus side, the way I've implemented it you can *usually* just grab a class or two instead of taking the whole library.

Comment: @zsharp, you really should have mentioned what you were trying to do:  you can use string.Join() for this!

Answer (score 24):

Better to use a for loop:

```
int itemCount = Items.Count;
for (int i = 0; i < itemCount; i++)
{
    var item = Items[i];

    // do something with item

    if (i != itemCount - 1)
    {
        // do another thing with item
    } 
}
```

Comment: +1 though this only works if the Items collection is indexed.

Comment: ...of course the notion of the last item in a collection is meaningless if the collection isn't indexed.

Comment: @Jon: Not at all. An `IEnumerable<T>` is inherently ordered but not indexed.

Comment: (Or perhaps more accurately, it's inherently ordered, but doesn't have random access by index, nor does it provide a count up front.)

Comment: thanks for answer, but have to give it to jon skeet because his solution still uses foreach which worked out.

Answer (score 4):

```
foreach (Item i in Items.Take(Items.Count - 1))
{
      do something with i;
      do another thing with i (but not if last item in collection);
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work, since it doesn't perform the first operation with the last item.

Comment: Yep, the first operation should be repeated after the loop for the last item.

Answer (score 2):

How about a for loop instead of a foreach.

```
for (int i = 0; i < Items.Count; i++) {
    //do something with i;
    if (i == Items.Count - 1) {
        //do another thing with Items[Items.count - 1];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use LINQ (if you use C#-3.0):

```
    foreach (Item i in items.Take(Items.Count - 1))
    {
...
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

As Jon Siegel pointed out:

> ...of course the notion of the last
>   item in a collection is meaningless if
>   the collection isn't indexed.

That said, suppose you want to do something for every item in an `IEnumerable<T>` except for one, that one being whichever happens to be the last one arbitrarily visited by an enumerator. Fine:

```
IEnumerator<Item> e = Items.GetEnumerator();
e.MoveNext();

while (e.Current != null)
{
    Item i = e.Current;
    // do something with i;

    if e.MoveNext()
    {
        // do another thing with i
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

looks like this is what you were trying to solve.

```
List<string> list = getList();
string.Join(", ", list.ToArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

i'd feel pretty dirty writing this but it might solve your problem.

```
Item last = null;

foreach (Item i in Items)
{
      last = i;
}

foreach (Item i in Items)
 {
      do something with i;

      if (i!=last){
            do another thing with i (but not if last item in collection);
      }
 }
```

Comment: Not the best way: Here you 1 more time loop through the Items collection, and in a case Item has some complex logic in Equals method, this will hurt the performance (this line: "if (i!=last){").

Comment: @Kamarey: That's a good explanation as to why you should "feel pretty dirty writing this".

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this logic as in  button click event..

```
namespace LastEnumItem
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        List<string> lst = new List<string>(); 
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for(int i=0; i<=10 ; i++)
            {
                lst.Add("string " + i.ToString());
            }
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string lastitem = lst[lst.Count-1];
            foreach (string str in lst)
            {
                if (lastitem != str)
                {
                    // do something
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Last Item :" + str);
                }
            }
        }


    }
}
```